# Style Issue with Badges Background and visited: Link on Profile Page

Tags: bug, user-interface

There are few badges I have which I click to see their meaning and why I earned them. But CSS for dark background badges name doesn't looks correct. All visited badges text colour changes to blue which makes that badge name almost unreadable. I am using Chrome on Macbook OS X 10.10. Not sure if others having the same problem.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm I noticed that on multiple occasions, never thought to raise a bug though :)

Comment: Same here :) but I recently earned `mortarboard` badge and I couldn't see due to this so, I raised the bug B| @Bachovski

Comment: still the same after 2 years, this should be fixed :/